# Spring-Boot: how to access multiple JMS broker-url's

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms

In Spring-Boot the default ActiveMQ (JMS) properties are:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://192.168.1.210:9876
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=secret
```

if I want to send to more than one broker-url or listen different broker-urls how to do it？

Comment: are those other brokers not activemq brokers?

Comment: all are activemq broers but hasdifferent address(not cluster)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access two different brokers with the default `Spring-Boot` auto configuration.

For resolving this you have to create your own configuration Bean like in the following example:

```
@Configuration
class JmsUtilsConfiguration {

    @Value("${activemq.broker-one.url}")
    private String brokerOneUrl;

    // Im my case, broker-two is secured -> hence username and password need to be configured
    @Value("${activemq.broker-two.url}")
    private String brokerTwoUrl;

    @Value("${activemq.broker-two.username}")
    private String brokerTwoUser;

    @Value("${activemq.broker-two.password}")
    private String brokerTwoPwd;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactoryOne() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerOneUrl);
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactoryTwo() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerTwoUrl);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setUserName(brokerTwoUser);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setPassword(brokerTwoPwd);
        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    // JmsListenerContainerFactory declarations
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactoryOne(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactoryTwo(
            @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactoryTwo") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
    
    // JMS Template Declaration
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplateOne() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactoryOne());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplateTwo() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactoryTwo());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

}
```

In my `application.yml` I just refer to the injected propertie (**without** setting the default `spring.activemq` ones):

```
activemq:
  broker-one:
    url: tcp://localhost:61616
    local-queue: TEST.LOCAL.INBOUND
  broker-two:
    url: failover:(ssl://myremote-amq-1:61617,ssl://myremote-amq-2:61617)?jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false&timeout=5000&maxReconnectDelay=10000
    username: myuser
    password: mypass
    remote-queue: TEST.REMOTE.QUEUE
```

and in my listener Bean (assuming I just want to consume from both queues)

```
@Component
public class ConsumeQueuesBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumeQueuesBean.class);

    @JmsListener(destination = "${activemq.broker-one.local-queue}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactoryOne")
    public void onMessageReceiveB1(final Message message) throws JMSException {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            String text = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            LOGGER.info(text);
        }
    }


    @JmsListener(destination = "${activemq.broker-two.remote-queue}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactoryTwo")
    public void onMessageReceivedB2(final Message message) throws JMSException {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            String text = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            LOGGER.info(text);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the `jmsTemplates` defined in the config for posting message to the broker you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.activemq.broker-url= # URL of the ActiveMQ broker. Auto-generated by default. For instance `tcp://localhost:61616`
spring.activemq.in-memory=true # Specify if the default broker URL should be in memory. Ignored if an explicit broker has been specified.
spring.activemq.password= # Login password of the broker.
spring.activemq.user= # Login user of the broker.
```

Make `spring.activemq.in-memory=false`. If it is true, then it will read from memory and you will get another one. Hope it will help.

### Resource Link:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: thanks a lot ,In our system there are two mq clusters,I want to use them how to set two different broker-url. kindly like read different data from diffrent db in one application。