# ActiveMQ Consumer failed to consume message on request queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

**Process:**

App A is creating a consumer connection on startup to "REQUEST QUEUE"
in remote Active MQ Broker. App B is pushing request into the "REQUEST
QUEUE", and the same is consumed by App A. App A produces response
into another queue "RESPONSE QUEUE".

App A is using ActiveMQ connection factory and Spring DMLC for
consuming the message.

What I understand from Spring DMLC is, it continuously polls on queue
for message.

**Problem:**

App A initially consumes request on app restart. But fails to consume the request second time when an another request is made a day after. Even the consumer goes down on the arrival of the second request.

**So far tried:**

The issue exists only in LIVE.And as per observation consumer is not able process/receive incoming message after a certain period(30 minutes).
I tried with same broker setup in other environments, but unfortunately couldn't re-produce. I have tried every other link but all in vain.

**Looking out for pointers:**

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm making use of
ActiveMQ connection for both consuming and producing ?

Possible pointers on what configuration to look out for debugging the issue.

**Code:**

Message Poller Configuration Code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan
@Slf4j
public class MessagePoller
{
    @Value("${outbound.queue}")
    private String outboundQueue;

    private final BrokerProperties brokerProperties;

    @Autowired
    public MessagePoller(BrokerProperties brokerProperties) {this.brokerProperties = brokerProperties;}

    @Bean(name = CONNECTION_FACTORY)
    @Primary
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
    {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerProperties.getUrl());
        connectionFactory.setUserName(brokerProperties.getUser());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(brokerProperties.getPassword());
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory()
    {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        factory.setErrorHandler(getErrorHandler());
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
        factory.setPubSubDomain(false);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name = OUTBOUND_JMS_TEMPLATE)
    public JmsTemplate outboudJmsTemplate(
            @Qualifier(CONNECTION_FACTORY)
                    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setPubSubDomain(false);
        template.setDefaultDestinationName(outboundQueue);
        return template;
    }

    private ErrorHandler getErrorHandler()
    {
        return exception -> log.error("Exception thrown from consumer", exception);
    }
}
```

Message Listener Code:

```java
@JmsListener(
        destination = "requestQueue",
        containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory"
)
public void onMessage(Message<String> jmsMessage)
{
    log.info("TriggerJobOnRequestService.onMessage() starts");
    log.info("Incoming request message: {}", jmsMessage);
    Integer deliveryCount = jmsMessage.getHeaders().get("JMSXDeliveryCount", Integer.class);

    log.info("Payload : {}", jmsMessage.getPayload());
    log.info("Headers : {}", jmsMessage.getHeaders());
    log.info("Delivery Count : {}", deliveryCount);
    //Processing Code logic
    log.info("TriggerJobOnRequestService.onMessage() ends");
}
```

ActiveMQ connection url:

```
spring.activemq.url=failover://(tcp://mqueue05.net:61616,tcp://mqueue06.net:61616,tcp://mqueue07.net:61616,tcp://mqueue08.net:61616)?randomize=false&timeout=100&initialReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectAttempts=10
```

Comment: @Justin Bertram . Do you like to share any pointers on the issue ?

Comment: I don't have any pointers at the moment.

Comment: @Justin Bertam At least is the code fundamentally wrong by any chance?

Comment: I'm not sure. I try to avoid Spring JMS whenever I can. I find using the JMS API directly is simpler and more powerful.

Comment: If you're using spring-boot, you don't need `@EnableJms` and `@ComponentScan` annotations. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65110016/628006) how I did use `@Configuration` to access two brokers with minimal configuration. Note also that the `@Configuration` bean is necessary only if you want to access two brokers. Otherwise just the `application.yml` properties are enough to access one (local or remote) broker.